# How to see if a value in one vector is in between any two values in another vector

Tags: r, dummy-variable

I have two vectors in date time format, and I would like to know if  any of the date time stamps in vector A fall in between any of the two given date time stamps in vector B.

```
data <- tibble(
  Col_A = structure(c(1514935860, 1514936280, 1514946120, 1515090600, 1515090600, 1515095040), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")),
  Col_B = structure(c(1517564040, 1517564340, 1517564640, 1517564940, 1517565240, 1517565540), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"))
```

I have tried this,

```
check <- data$Col_A
data$dummy <- ifelse(data$Col_B %in% check, "1", "0")
```

but this only returns the data points in Col_A within the entire range of Col_B, but I need the code to check every interval of two date time stamps in Col_B.

Comment: What do you mean with 'any of the two given date time stamps'? What exactly are, in this example, the datetime-ranges you want to check on? Can you maybe give the expected output for this data?

Comment: I would like to check each timestamps in Col_A and see if there are between the first two intervals in col_b and then the second and third interval in col_b and so on until the last two intervals for col_b. Then, check the second timestamp in col_a against the first two intervals in col_b and then the second and third interval and so on.

Comment: The expected output will look something like;

Comment: Col_C = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0). Here, each 1 means that the timestamp in col_a was between any of the two timestamps in col_b, and zero means that it was not in between any two of the timestamps. For example, in col_a I have the time stamp 2018-02-02 14:55:00, and in col_b I have 2018-02-02 14:50:00 and 2018-02-02 15:00:00. So in this case it will equal 1, but had the timestamp in col_a not existed it will equal 0.

Comment: Please note that your Col_A values are all from '2018-01' and Col_B are from '2018-02'

Comment: That is not my entire dataset, just a sample of both. The actual col_a has 13,000 and col_b has 400,000 entries.

Answer (score 0):

If we need to do this on `any` combination,

```
data$check <- combn(data$Col_B, 2, FUN = function(x) 
     +(any(dplyr::between(data$Col_A, x[1], x[2]))))
```

#### data

```
data <- structure(list(Col_A = structure(c(1514935860, 1514936280, 1514946120, 
1515090600, 1515090600, 1515095040), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), Col_B = structure(c(1517564040, 1517564340, 1517564640, 
1517564940, 1517565240, 1517565540), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Comment: @RonanDunne your example data works fine without any error

Comment: I tried using the code and it returned the following; Error in matrix(r, nrow = len.r, ncol = count) : 
  invalid 'ncol' value (too large or NA)
In addition: Warning message:
In combn(data$col_b, 2, FUN = function(x) +(any(dplyr::between(data$col_a,  :
  NAs introduced by coercion to integer range

Comment: I used the data as in my post (updated).  it is not giving any error

Comment: Could it be that my actual dataset has 13000 entries in col_a and 400,000 entries in col_b

Comment: @RonanDunne could be as `combn` will have to do those pairwise cases

Comment: Is there any way around that?

Comment: when you say any two, have to do the combn.  Or else have to `order` the rows and then may have to check only a subset of pairs

Comment: Could I break the col_b vector up into different vectors and do it that way? So each vector is smaller than the large vector